# I'm getting error like this while creating react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

```
-->
create-react-app : File C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.ps1 cannot be loaded because running
scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ create-react-app demo
```

Answer (score 65):

I think you are using Windows, I came across the same problem and it's because of a security feature in your system.

1. Open powershell as an administrator.
2. Run the following command `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`
3. Try again.

This worked for me.

Sources: https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-powershell-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/

Answer (score 22):

Make sure you remove `create-react-app` from `npm` globally and use `npx create-react-app {project_name}` to generate a react app.

```
npm uninstall --global create-react-app
npx create-react-app sample
```

also, make sure that your npm version is after 5.2 while doing these.

Comment: This works, without uninstalling globally.  Can you explain why you recommended that step?

Answer (score 16):

Run power shell as admin

1. Windows Start
2. Search for "Windows Powershell"
3. Right click Windows Powershell
4. Click Run as Administrator (Grant in "User Account Control" if shows up)
5. Type `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`
6. Select/Type yes [Y]

Answer (score 3):

Simply run **Power shell** as **administrator**
then execute the command:***set-executionpolicy remotesigned***

Answer (score 3):

try this command : npx create-react-app yourappname

Answer (score 3):

This error comes because Microsoft changed some PowerShell execution policies for your security.

We can create react app from mainly two places.

1. **Command Prompt** - You can easily create new react project without facing any issue.
2. **Powershell terminal in Visual code** - If you not disables new policies of powershell yet then you will face such problem. You need follow some steps to disable these security features.

- Run power shell as administrator
- Type **set-executionpolicy remotesigned**
- There will be 5 options.
- You need to type **Y** (for [Y] Yes) and click Enter button.
- Now you will be able to create react app in your visual code.

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

- run cmd as adminstrator then
- cd to the folder you want to create the app in it and type the following

  ### create-react-app myapp

  this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

if you're a Windows OS user open your Powershell and paste the following command on your PowerShell
cmd -> set-executionpolicy remotesigned.

Answer (score 0):

Just stop your node server in "task manager", and start. After that try to install with **npx** or **npm**.

Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, I also got this error.
This error comes when you try to write the command create-react-app

when you type the command npm install -g create-react-app, after running this command you should restart the command prompt or command powershell whatever you are using.
After restarting command prompt now you can type create-react-app  cmd.